# Sitefinity live site error

Tags: sitefinity

we just launched our new site [YunGoal](http://www.yungoal.com) developed in sitefinity, but how ever we are constantly running into these error msgs with every few clicks, this is really interfering with our user experience, does anyone know what is causing this, We tried changing various settings， look for bugs on our pages all to no avail. we really appreciate any help we can get, thanks in advance.

[image: sitefinity error msg screen shot]

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to be able to help you, please also include relevant code & error messages within the body of your question rather than in images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these instructions when using MySQL with Sitefinity:
http://docs.sitefinity.com/administration-persist-multilingual-fields-in-separate-tables-for-each-language